# Trust Self Signed Certificate in Xulrunner app for https urls

Tags: javascript, ssl, xulrunner, self-signed

I developed a small xulrunner application, which works fine when I am able to use http requests.

Now I want my xulrunner to open my https remote web page (This has self signed certificate).
I would like to how I can make my application accept this certificate and make my https certificate work.

How to make my xulrunner app trust the self signed certificate of my web server (HTTPS).

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `cert_override.txt` file to the default profile of your application (`defaults/profile/cert_override.txt`) - this file will be copied to any new profile and make sure that some certificates will be accepted despite not being trusted. It's easiest to create a permanent exception for your web site in Firefox, you can then use the `cert_override.txt` file from your Firefox profile (that way you don't need to decipher the format).

Comment: I did that, I am unable to make this work.Is there anything I might be missing.

Comment: As I said, that file will only apply to new profiles. If you have a profile already it won't have any effect.

Comment: I've also tried dropping this file in that folder (and I deleted my profiles) and I also could not get it to work.  First, it did not copy it into the new profile, but even when I did that manually, it still gave me the same error about not being able to use a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I would do same as Wladimir Palant answer.

But, make sure, hostname is fully qualified domain name (e.g. something.com, instead of just myserver).

There would be different entry for myserver 443 as compared to something.com 443 in firefox cert_override.txt file. Due to this issue, even though I had entry for myserver 443 I was not able to get exemption for https:// something/. I had to set it up as https://something.com/ with right entry for something.com 443 in cert_override.txt file.

Please replace .com with your domain/sub-domain name.